# Is 1ms Java timer delay too quick?

Tags: java, timer

```
Timer timer = new Timer(true);
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask, 0, 1);  // 1 = 1ms delay between each iteration
```

Each time it triggers it runs a super quick operation which essentially take no time at all: basically it takes the current milliseconds elapsed value and increments it while doing a quick lookup in a Map where the millis is the key.

Do you think 1ms delay would be too fast? Is this going to bog down the system? Are there any dangers in trying to use this super fast timer?

Comment: How often do you _need_ it to be done?

Comment: Yes, I think it's too quick, although that's based on gut feel and not really any hard evidence.  What's your goal, why do you want to read a timer at all?

Comment: One potential problem is some platforms can only time accurately to several ms. (Windows for example schedules tasks in 16 ms increments).

Comment: Depends on what is in that Map, which you completely do not describe at all! If the key has a 1-ms granularity then you're basically stuck with a 1-ms granularity of your timer. The danger of *needing* a 1ms timing is that occasionally it might not succeed to maintain that rate, especially when a garbage collection run drives by.

Comment: do you have a requirements doc? if so you should look at that

Comment: Did you consider using a while loop? You could toss a Thread.sleep(1); Usually that isn't recommended, but for a 1ms delay, it might be reasonable. How do you want it to behave if it falls behind?

Comment: If it falls behind forget that something was missed. This is not a critical thing ... in rare cases you might miss one or two captions for an entire movie ... just guessing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That **depends**.

Ask yourself these questions:

- how often do I absolutely **need** that value to be checked?
- how quick would be **acceptable**?
- how much of your systems CPU time are you **willing to sacrifice** on this task?

One ms can be long (high end gaming PC) or very, very short (older gen smartphone) and depending on your CPU architecture you'll end up stuffing **one of many** cores or **the one and only core** with calculating time differences.

As for your data structure: you'll probably need something like a sorted map containing the start as key and duration as one field of the value. You'd fetch the closest key less than your time and check if the caption stored is still valid... or similar

Comment: It absolutely at the slowest needs to run every 1 second because a new caption to the movie can occur at any given second and no more than one per second. A movie will be playing either in a browser or in a media player and this will be overlayed on top of the movie. I can lose some CPU time but don't want to lose too much where the movie starts lagging or something.

Comment: Ah. So you're displaying captions in a movie. So basically everything faster than 1/30th second (or roughly 30ms) will be wasted resources anyways. Considering the timenthe viewers will need to **read** the text on screen I'd guess with 250ms  checks you're pretty  safe.

Comment: Cool ... I will try that Jan. Thanks.

Comment: I ended up going with 1sec as the period and it works like a charm. I watched two 2-hour long movies and the captions didn't mess up once!! Thanks for all the help everyone.

Comment: @BrianTHannan Thanks for the feedback :-)

Answer (score 4):

Maybe.  A lot can happen in a millisecond on contemporary computers so it depends on lots of things.  You probably should figure out the slowest rate acceptable and then pick something reasonable between 1 and that number.  This will execute more around 86,400,000 times a day.  Does that make sense for what you are trying to accomplish?

EDIT: As some of the comments to the question note, there might be a fundamental flaw in this approach if you assume that the timer will always succeed to execute at the rate you have provided.  You can never make this assumption regardless of the rate.  It's hard to tell because there are very few details but I have a sense you should look into using queues instead of a Map.

Comment: It's a timer for a movie timeline where you hit play and it starts the timer and updates the timeline value. It looks at the millis as the lookup key in a Map that has the caption for that millisecond. My issue is I'm wondering if I have to change it so the key to the map is not the exact millis but rather the number of millis to the second. This way I can use the elapsed time as the lookup. Right now I have to use elapsed millis time as the lookup ... but I can change that if doing this timer task every 1 ms is bad or problematic.

Comment: Is the caption associated with a range of time?  If so, a Map is probably not the best option.  If that's what you are doing, you want to do something like have a class that is a range i.e. it has a start and end time and the caption.  Then you put these in a SortedSet or and a List that you keep sorted.  Then you set your timer to whatever refresh rate you want, and when it fires, you do a binary search for a caption.

Comment: JimmyJames, that might work better. I will try this as well.

Answer (score 0):

"Do you think 1ms delay would be too fast?" - Yes, and it will not be able to start task each millisecond (especially on-loading), you can test it yourself (with small example below).

"Is this going to bog down the system?" - actually not very much (I mean mostly CPU time). If you run your operation for example in a loop and will not make any pause, you will get much more load. Your system will spend big amount of time on context switch to start your task, officials it is inevitable overhead, but if you execute very simple task this overhead will be comparable with your useful workload.

"Are there any dangers in trying to use this super fast timer?" - as you wrote above " quick lookup in a Map where the millis is the key" you use millis as a key but you will not run each millisecond so your logic if count to be corrupted.

```
    static int inc = 0;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {


        TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {                
                inc++;
            }
        };

        Timer timer = new Timer(true);
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask, 0, 1);        
        Thread.sleep(500000);
        timer.cancel();
        timer.purge();
        System.out.println(inc);
    }
```